# How to handle DLLs in GAC

Tags: 2013, farm-solution

Lets say I have a third party webpart which uses a DLL and pushes it into the GAC. Moreover I have custom webpart which I developed which also uses the same DLL but in a different version which is also pushed into the GAC.

Due to the fact that the DLL is already in the GAC I cannot deploy the third party solution.

What is the recommended way to handle such issues?

Comment: why you can't deploy it ?

Answer (score 1):

> Lets say I have a third party webpart which uses a DLL and pushes it
>   into the GAC. Moreover I have custom webpart which I developed which
>   also uses the same DLL but in a different version which is also pushed
>   into the GAC.

You can have different versions of DLLs in GAC.

I got two different version's DLLs in GAC as shown in picture below,

[image]

**Edit**

OR if you can [add app.config to your webpart](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/24346/how-do-you-create-webpart-specific-config-files) and then add [Assembly Binding Redirect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2fc472t2%28VS.80%29.aspx).

Comment: And how would I do that? Because right now SharePoint does not accept two solutions with the same library which only differ by version. It is not a question that the GAC supports it. My problem is that I need to know how to do this via a solution package.

Comment: when you deploy your solution it should put DLLs in gac itself, however you can drag and drop them to assembly as well if you are using Server 2003, 2008, what do you mean SharePoint does not accept two solutinos ?

Comment: My solution, which I have developed, is already deployed. When I now try to deploy the third party solution I get the error message __Error: Cannot add the specified assembly to the global assembly cache: Newtonsoft.Json.dll.__

Comment: In your webpart solution find the dll "Newtonsoft.Json.dll" and then set its property "Copy Local" to false and rebuild solution and re-deploy it, should solve the issue, however I would recommend you to use web application's bin folder if webparts will be used within single web app.

Answer (score 0):

If you need the newest version, upgrade your solution to fit the newest third party requirements und only take the newest DLL.

Comment: Would be an option but I'm using a newer version than the third party solution. Therefore this way is not an option for me.

Comment: Ok, got it wrong. Thought you use a DLL from a third Party solution. Nevermind